WP backend, Show only own comments (give to users who wrote/published/assigned) posts
I want to limit this in the WP admin:

Show only own comments (given to users who wrote/published/assigned)
posts (Admins excluded).
also the filters numbers will be assigned to user posts not as im the screenshot all website comments counted.

Regards


Using the comments_pre_query filter, this seemed to work well in development and testing:
/**
 * @param null $comment_data Return an array of comment data to short-circuit WP's comment query.
 * @param WP_Comment_Query $query WP_Comment_Query instance, passed by reference.
 */
add_filter( 'comments_pre_query', static function ( $comment_data, $query ) {
    // Limit to admin area.
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return null;
    }

    // Exclude administrators.
    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    // Don't override existing limit to specific author(s).
    if ( ! empty( $query->query_vars['post_author__in'] ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    // Include definition for function if missing.
    if ( ! function_exists( 'get_current_screen' ) ) {
        require_once 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php';
    }

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    // If screen has not yet been defined, do a basic check.
    if ( is_null( $screen ) && str_contains( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'edit-comments.php' ) ) {
        $screen = (object) array(
            'id' => 'edit-comments',
        );
    }

    // If screen not identified, bail.
    if ( empty( $screen ) || ! is_object( $screen ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    // If incorrect screen, bail.
    if ( 'edit-comments' !== $screen->id ) {
        return null;
    }

    // Limit comments to posts authored by current user.
    $query->query_vars['post_author__in'] = array( get_current_user_id() );

    return null;
}, 10, 2 );


Thank you Caleb. the code worked as needed.
I'm trying to learn PHP but I have no time enough yet.
I appreciate your time and work for this.
Regards
